# key authentication using libssh in a C program

Tags: c, authentication, key, libssh

I want to login to remote device using libssh without specifying password in my code. I have already tested password authentication and it works fine. I have tried many combinations of key authentication APIs of libssh but it does not seem to work.

For key authentication, I have written this function:

```
    int vs_ssh_authenticate(vsBasestation_t *bs)
    {
      int auth = -1;
      ssh_key pkey, privkey;
      #ifdef KEY_AUTHENTICATION
      char *password;
      password="sample";
      auth = ssh_userauth_password(bs->session,NULL,password);
      if (auth==SSH_AUTH_ERROR)
      {
         fprintf(stderr,"Authentication with password failed: %s\n",ssh_get_error(bs->session));
         return auth;
      }
      #else
      if(ssh_pki_import_pubkey_file("~/.ssh/key.pub",&pkey) == SSH_OK)
      {
          if(ssh_pki_import_privkey_file("~/.ssh/key",NULL,
                                           NULL,NULL,&privkey) == SSH_OK)
          {
              auth = ssh_userauth_publickey(bs->session, NULL, privkey);
          }
      }
      #endif
      return auth;
    }
```

Now, if public key of client machine is present in "authorized_keys" file at server then this mechanism works otherwise access denied response is sent by Server. How should I copy public key of client to server from this program?

Thanks.

Comment: ssh_userauth_publickey_auto() mention on http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_authentication.html seems to to what you want

Comment: Stian, I have edited my question and added function which I used for authentication. My concern is how can I copy the public key of client to server using my program?

Comment: The counterpart key is supposed to already be present in the server, stored in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys . File permission and ownership has to be correct on both the keyfile, and the directories

Comment: Ok. It should always be done manually? or is there any API available in libssh module to do that. Although, I could not find any such API.

Comment: No such API, but you could always download the file, check if the key is there already, if not, add it and reupload.

And if file is not there at all, create it.

NB, permissions on the directory and file is important, else the keyfile will be rejected

Comment: ok got it. Thanks a lot :)